# Is there an online tool to test all HTTP methods against some public server?

Tags: http, webdav

Is there an online tool that can help constructing proper HTTP request to to test all HTTP/WEBDAV methods against some public server?

By all methods I mean at least the following:

- GET
- PUT
- DELETE
- MERGE
- OPTIONS
- PROPFIND
- MKACTIVITY

Comment: That's not a programming question, this should be migrated.

Comment: Not an online tool, but Litmus helps you with most of the webdav methods. Not MKACTIVITY though, that's a webdav extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found any online tool, but [WFetch](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=21625) seems to be a good alternative for Windows to construct any kind of custom HTTP request.